# Como puedo mostrar la información de un formulario dentro del widget Stepper

Tags: flutter, dart

Bueno lo que estoy haciendo es hacer cada que el usuario llene unos inputs dentro del widget de Stepper este al darle click en guardar muestre la información que se lleno en el paso que debe ser. Lo que estoy haciendo ahorita es que tengo una lista con todos los pasos que ocupo y cada ve que le da click en guardar este ejecuta la función onStepContinue() del Stepper. Lo que hace en est funcion es agregar a una lista un objeto con los datos del formulario el cual despues actualiza mi provider y aumenta en 1 un contador que tengo para que avanze al siguiente paso.
La siguiente imagen es lo que llevo hecho:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo siguiente imagen es como debe de quedar una vez que se haya dado click en guardar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que hace funcionar mi stepper:

```
 Widget _stepper(BuildContext context) {
    BuquesProvider _buquesProvider =
        Provider.of<BuquesProvider>(context, listen: false);
    List<Data> dataForm = _buquesProvider.data![widget.index].data;
    List<Step> estatus = [
      steps('Arribo', pickers()),
      steps('Amarre del 1er cabo', pickers()),
      steps('Totalmente atracado', pickers()),
      steps('Arribo de autoridades', const Text('')),
      steps('Salida de autoridades', const Text('')),
      steps('Inicio de operacion', pickers()),
      steps('Arrastes', const Text('')),
      steps('Termino de operaciones', pickers()),
      steps('Vista de autoridades al zarpe', const Text('')),
      steps('Termino de la visita', const Text('')),
      steps('Liberacion del ultimo cabo', pickers()),
    ];
    return Stepper(
      currentStep: currStep,
      steps: estatus,
      onStepContinue: () {
        Data data = Data(fecha: dateController.text, hora: timeController.text);
        dataForm.add(data);
        _buquesProvider.data![widget.index].data = dataForm;
        setState(() {
          if (estatus.length > currStep + 1) currStep++;
          _buquesProvider.data![widget.index].estado = currStep;
          _buquesProvider.notify();
          timeController.clear();
          dateController.clear();
        });
      },
      controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails controls) {
        return stepperButton(controls);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: La verdad que no termino de entender la duda. ¿Podrías replantearla?

Comment: Al inicio va mostrar un formulario y una vez que le de click en guardar tiene que mostrar lo que se lleno en el formulario pero como texto plano. El problema que tengo es que no se me ocurre como actualizar el stepper para que muestre la información que se lleno en ese paso en vez de mostrar los campos de texto.

Comment: No se me ocurre ninguna forma de hacer eso. Creo que podrías buscar algún plugin/paquete o hacerte algo custom tú mismo. Podrías ver cómo está hecho el widget stepper internamente como referencia. Ojalá que alguien más pueda echarte un cable.

Comment: Ayer en la tarde se me ocurrió hacerlo con una listview en vez de usar el stepper y cada que le da guardar aumenta en 1 un contador que tengo el cual hace que muestre el siguiente paso que se tiene que mostrar

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar `im_stepper` lo puedes encontrar en pub.dev, yo lo uso para otros fines, pero supongo que te puede servir para lo que quieres hacer:

```
IconStepper(
      icons: [
        Icon(AyudaTodoIcons.apuntes,
            size: 25, color: activade == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
        Icon(Icons.documento,
            size: 25, color: active == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
        Icon(Icons.notificacion,
            size: 25, color: active == 2 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
        Icon(Icons.comprar,
            size: 25, color: active == 3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
        Icon(Icons.boton,
            size: 25, color: active == 4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
        Icon(Icons.tarjeta,
            size: 25, color: active == 5 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
        Icon(Icons.ubicacion,
            size: 25, color: active == 6 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
      ],
      activeStep: active,
      lineColor: Colors.black,
      lineDotRadius: 1,
      stepColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      activeStepColor: Colors.white,
      stepPadding: 5,
      stepReachedAnimationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      nextButtonIcon: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_right_sharp,
        size: 30,
      ),
      previousButtonIcon: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_left_sharp,
        size: 30,
      ),
      activeStepBorderWidth: 2,
      onStepReached: (index) {
        setState(() {
          active = index;
        });
      },
    );
```

Esa es una de las opciones que te ofrece.